# Windows 8 steam compatibility

Tags: steam, windows-8

I have literally just bought my first ever computer and thought Windows 8 seeing as it is the most up to date would be the best..  anyhow, I am trying to download steam so as to buy games and play 'em and it is telling me it isn't compatible.  What is? and where do I find it?

Comment: use this link to download steam for windows http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe

Comment: Are all your drivers up to date? It shouldn't matter for steam to run but i might be why you cant launch games. Also have you used the OFFICIAL installer? @PhilippSander has posted the link above.

Comment: Do you have Windows 8 Pro? You can't install programs other than the Windows Store Apps if you have the RT version. Not sure what kind of message you get if you try.

Answer (score 3):

Steam is compatible to windows 8, as are all games as far as I know. Basically, if it runs on windows 7 it'll run on windows 8. The issue you're having is related to something else, try looking further onto the specific message you are getting but it shouldn't have anything to do with steam compatibility.

Also, before anything else, try running it as Administrator. (right click the program / installer and hit Run as Admin and agree to the pop up message you'll get)